# Using Spring Boot 2.0 with Tomcat 7.0.82

Tags: spring-boot, embedded-tomcat-7

I have a project that uses Spring Boot 2.0.0.RC2. I need to deploy it to a customer environment using traditional deployment for Tomcat 7.0.82. 
I've managed to build a war that can be deployed successfully by configuring `web.xml` in a typical way for Spring applications (with DispatcherServlet) instead of using `SpringBootServletInitializer`.

I also would like to have a quick way of starting the app on local environment using an embedded Tomcat container by simply running the main method in the application class with `@SpringBootApplication` annotation. It works fine if I'm using the default Tomcat version (8.5.28). However, I would like to start the embedded container also in 7.0.82 version. This is important for me for another reason - I'm using SpringBootTest and it would be nice if those tests run on the exact same container as the customer environment. Unfortunately, I can't use the Spring Boot parent POM and override `tomcat.version` property.

I've tried `@SpringBootApplication(exclude = ServletWebServerFactoryAutoConfiguration.class)` create `TomcatServletWebServerFactory` bean manually

```
@Bean
public ServletWebServerFactory tomcatServletWebServerFactory() {
    return new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();
}
```

and add tomcat 7.0.82 dependencies explicitly in `pom.xml` (${tomcat.version} = 7.0.82):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-annotations-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-annotations-api</artifactId>
    <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-util</artifactId>
    <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
    <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
    <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
    <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

but I'm still getting a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tomcat/util/scan/StandardJarScanFilter` error.

Could you please advise if there is any way to meet my requirements?

Comment: By downgrading Spring Boot to the 1.5 branch. Spring Boot 2.0, requires a Servlet 3.1 container. Tomcat 7 is a Servlet 3.0 container.

Comment: I would like to avoid it if possible - I'd prefer finding a solution for Spring Boot 2.0 since I would like to have a support for JUnit5.

Comment: Spring Boot 2, requires Spring 5, which requires a Servlet 3.1 container. Your only option is to downgrade, if that is only for jUnit 5 there is also jUnit 5 support for Spring 4.3. See https://github.com/sbrannen/spring-test-junit5. Or upgrade to Tomcat 8.5 (which is the official 3.1 container).

Comment: @M.Deinum - I downgraded the version to 1.5.10.RELEASE and now I have the embedded container in 7.0.82 version. But what's interesting is that I looked into the dependency versions that Spring Boot 1.5.10.RELEASE is using Servlet API also in 3.1.0 version. Any idea why it works for 1.5.10.RELEASE and not for 2.0.0.RC2 then?

Comment: Because it isn't the minimal required version as that is Servlet 3.0 API.

Comment: Any source? I don't see it anywhere in the docs.

Comment: As stated it isn't in the Spring Boot docs it is in the Spring docs.

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot 2:
The minimum supported version of Tomcat is 8.5

Reference: https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-20-new-features-infrastructure-changes

Comment: Can you please share the reference to official document?

Comment: Here's the official Spring Boot release notes on GitHub: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0.0-M1-Release-Notes#tomcat
The link above can not be considered an official resource.